# angular method works in component but not dialog

Tags: angular, mapbox-gl

UPDATED TO INCLUDE FULL DIALOG CODE.

I have an angular app with a mapbox-gl map object. I want to set a layer of the map to be hidden/visible. In the component where the map is created, the map.setLayoutProperty() function is deifned and works like a charm. It is in a dialog however, that I want to toggle layers on/off. In the dialog, the map object gets passed in with no issues, but when I try and use the setLayoutProperty() funciton to toggle a layer, I get a runtime error telling me the function is not defined. 
Usage in map component that works fine:

```
    this._mapRef.setLayoutProperty( 'satellite-street', 'visibility', 'none');
```

Where dialog is created in map component:

```
  layerControl() {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.panelClass = 'layer-control-dialog';
    dialogConfig.position = { top: '0',
                              right: '20' };
    dialogConfig.data = {
      map: this._mapRef
    };

    const dialogRef =     this.layerControlDialogComponent.open(LayerControlDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
      data => {

        console.log('Dialog output: ', data.controls.acMgrName.touched )
      });

  }
```

Where map is passed in via the constructor in the dialog:

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material';
import { LngLat, Layer, Map } from 'mapbox-gl';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-layer-control',
  templateUrl: './layer-control-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layer-control-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class LayerControlDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  _layers = {
    markerLayer: true,
    polyLayer: true,
    satLayer: false,
    IFRLayer: false,
    VFRLayer: false,
    airspaceLayer: false
  }
  _map: Map;
  visibility = '';

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<LayerControlDialogComponent>,
               @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) map: Map) {
                 console.log('layer control dialog, map=', map);
                 this._map = map;
               }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSatShowToggle(e) {
    this._layers.satLayer = e.checked === true ? true : false;
    this.visibility = this._layers.satLayer === true ? 'visible' : 'none';
    console.log('this._map=', this._map);
    this._map.setLayoutProperty( 'satellite-street',
                                  'visibility',
                                  this.visibility);
  }
  onMarkerShowToggle(e) {
    this._layers.markerLayer = e.checked === true ? true : false;
  }
  onPolyShowToggle(e) {
    this._layers.polyLayer = e.checked === true ? true : false;
  }
  onRadioGroupToggle(e) {
    switch (e.value) {
      case 'vfrLayer':  this._layers.VFRLayer = true;
                        this._layers.IFRLayer = false;
                        this._layers.airspaceLayer = false;
                        break;
      case 'ifrLayer':  this._layers.VFRLayer = false;
                        this._layers.IFRLayer = true;
                        this._layers.airspaceLayer = false;
                        break;
      case 'airspaceLayer': this._layers.VFRLayer = false;
                        this._layers.IFRLayer = false;
                        this._layers.airspaceLayer = true;
                        break;
    }
  }

  close(e) {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

and finally , the runtime error:
[image]
I have the same imports, have verified the map object is getting passed into the dialog. What am I missing?

Thanks....

Comment: where is `onSatShowToggle` defined? in the dialog or the calling component?

Comment: it's defined in the dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having the dialog select the layers to display/hide, then return the status of each layer back to the map component. Map component then shows/hides layers based on return from the dialog. Seems a roundabout way of doing things, but it works!